# Connecting Outlook 2010 Public Folders

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, outlook, public-folders

I'm trying to connect to a Public Folder in Outlook 2010 with C# (Visual Studio 2010).
I copied following code from a [Microsoft Website](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310244/en-us):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // TODO: Add code here to start the application.
            Outlook._Application olApp = new Outlook.ApplicationClass();
            Outlook._NameSpace olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI"); Outlook._Folders oFolders;
            oFolders = olNS.Folders;
            Outlook.MAPIFolder oPublicFolder = oFolders["Public Folders"];
            oFolders = oPublicFolder.Folders;
            Outlook.MAPIFolder oAllPFolder = oFolders["All Public Folders"];
            oFolders = oAllPFolder.Folders;
            Outlook.MAPIFolder oMyFolder = oFolders["My Public Folder"];
            Console.Write(oMyFolder.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that "ApplicationClass" is redlined and I don't know what I've forgotten or done wrong.
Here's a [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7rxfoaPyK5QM3g3TVQwOU51Rm8/view?usp=sharing) with the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use interface

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application()
```

or disable embedding of Interop types for this assembly (References -> Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook (right click) -> Properties -> Set 'Embed Interop Types' to False)

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
Outlook._Application olApp = new Outlook.ApplicationClass();
```

to

```
Outlook._Application olApp = new Outlook._Application();
```